# Plot k-mean cluster with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, k-means

I'd like to know how can I plot this using ggplot2. bdata[,c(25:54)] are 30 columns from a data frame which have values of gene expresion, each column is a gene.

```
cl <- kmeans(t(bdata[,c(25:54)]), 3)
plot(t(bdata[,c(25:54)]), col = cl$cluster)
points(cl$centers, col = 1:3, pch = 8, cex=2)
```

How can I plot the kmeans cluster with ggplot2, to get the same plot that with plot function?

[image]

Comment: could you post a representative subset of your data (preferably using `dput()`)? Without it we're rather lost you see.

Answer (score 3):

So, I don't know what bdata is but here is an example with the iris dataframe:

```
iris %>% select(-Species) %>% # remove Species column
 kmeans(centers=3) ->        # do k-means clustering with 3 centers
 km                          # store result as `km`
```

So here there are 3 centers because we know there are 3 species in the dataset. For plotting, we want cluster to be a factor and not a continuous variable.

```
iris_clustered <- data.frame(iris, cluster=factor(km$cluster))
ggplot(iris_clustered, aes(x=Petal.Width, y=Sepal.Width, color=cluster, 
    shape=Species)) + geom_point()
```

[Image of resulting PCA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz7QB.png)

Comment: I have seen this example, but it's not the same for my data, here the data is in colums, but I have to transpose the data in order to do "kmeans", and I don't have 2 variable to plot in x and y exis like petal and sepal width.

Comment: If you want to use ggplot with a geom_point() layer, you need to provide an X and Y argument. You could use dplyr to subset the data to only plot the columns you want like 'data %>% select(1:30)' , and maybe there is something in tidyr to help transform your data to a for usable by ggplot? Hard to know without your data.